How to mailmerge with python including images?
I am trying to add one document with images, text etc. to another document. Is there an easy way other than xml.etree (which seems to corrupt the document on zip)? python-docx doesn't handle images at all well. I could also move to another document format, such as OpenDocument but not sure that's easy either...

Another option is to convert documents to a common format using pypandoc. This can handle various formats and could be more flexible.
example:
import pypandoc

def combine_documents(doc1_path, doc2_path, output_path):
    # Convert both documents to markdown or another format
    doc1_md = pypandoc.convert_file(doc1_path, 'markdown')
    doc2_md = pypandoc.convert_file(doc2_path, 'markdown')
    
    # Combine the contents
    combined_md = doc1_md + "\n\n" + doc2_md
    
    # Convert back to DOCX
    pypandoc.convert_text(combined_md, 'docx', format='markdown', outputfile=output_path)

combine_documents('doc1.docx', 'doc2.docx', 'combined.docx')

